# PHP / MySQL: If Else condition doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, mysql, json, datetime

Based on my question above, currently, I created a booking system. This system is to book the meeting room. In this system, admin responsible to book the meeting room after get the request from staff. Thus, admin need to key in some information such as:

1) Requester's Email

2) Room

3) Purpose

4) Start Time and End Time

The most important parameter is Room, Purpose and Start Time & End Time. For example, if Room  B booked on Today from 8.00 AM to 10.00 PM, then, other staff cannot booked Room B during that time.

My problem is, although I do If else to check the parameter, it still can book the room although the date and time have clashed.

Below is my code:

```
<?php

require_once "../../../config/configPDO.php";
require_once "../../../config/check.php";
$Email = $_SESSION['login_user'];
$UserID = $_SESSION['userid'];

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   

    require '../../../config/PHPMailer/Mailer/Exception.php';
    require '../../../config/PHPMailer/Mailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require '../../../config/PHPMailer/Mailer/SMTP.php';

    $Requested_by = $_POST['Requested_by'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $timeFrom = $_POST['timeFrom'];
    $timeTo = $_POST['timeTo'];

    //to add %20 for space
    $from = rawurlencode($timeFrom);
    $to = rawurlencode($timeTo);

    $Meeting_Description = $_POST['Meeting_Description'];
    $Room_ID = $_POST['Room_ID'];
    $Admin_email = $_POST['Admin_email'];
    $Remark = $_POST['Remark'];
    $Book_Status = $_POST['Book_Status'];
    $StartTime = $date." ".$timeFrom;
    $EndTime = $date." ".$timeTo;

     //check start end, room no
    $url2 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/displayBookingData?timeStart=$timeTo&timeEnd=$timeFrom&Room_ID=$Room_ID&Book_No=";
    $data2 = file_get_contents($url2);
    $json2 = json_decode($data2);
    $results = $json2->bookingList;

    $url3 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/selectRoom?Room_Desc=&Fac_ID=&Room_ID=$Room_ID";
    $data3 = file_get_contents($url3);
    $json3 = json_decode($data3);
    $results2 = $json3->roomList;

    $url4 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/getUserInfo?userID=$UserID";
    $data4 = file_get_contents($url4);
    $json4 = json_decode($data4);
    $results3 = $json4->userList;

    if(empty($results)){

        if (isset($results3[0])){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO booking(Requested_by, Book_Date, StartTime, EndTime, Meeting_Description, Room_ID, Admin_email, Remark, Book_Status) 
        VALUES(:Requested_by, :Book_Date, :StartTime, :EndTime, :Meeting_Description, :Room_ID, :Admin_email, :Remark, :Book_Status)";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $query->bindparam(':Requested_by', $Requested_by);
        $query->bindparam(':Book_Date', $date);
        $query->bindparam(':StartTime', $StartTime);
        $query->bindparam(':EndTime', $EndTime); 
        $query->bindparam(':Meeting_Description', $Meeting_Description);
        $query->bindparam(':Room_ID', $Room_ID);
        $query->bindparam(':Admin_email', $Admin_email);
        $query->bindparam(':Remark', $Remark);
        $query->bindparam(':Book_Status', $Book_Status);
        $query->execute();

            if(!empty($results)){

            echo "<script>alert('Something were going wrong. Please try again.')</script>
                    <script>window.location = '../../dashboard/admin/dashboard_admin.php'</script>";
            }else{

            echo "<script>alert('Data sucessfully saved!')</script>
                    <script>window.location = '../../dashboard/admin/dashboard_admin.php'</script>";
            }

            }else{

                echo "<script>alert('Invalid email address')</script>
                    <script>window.location = 'manual_booking_admin.php'</script>";
            }

    }else{

        echo "<script>alert('The time range you are selected is conflicted with another meeting')</script>
            <script>window.location = 'manual_booking_admin.php'</script>";
    }

?>
```

Can I know what is problem with my code?

Comment: Where exactly is the code that checks for the date clash. I'm not seeing it.

Comment: already added the comment line, please check

Comment: Are you missing a parameter at the end of this url string?  `$url2 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/displayBookingData?timeStart=$timeTo&timeEnd=$timeFrom&Room_ID=$Room_ID&Book_No=";` The Book_No= at the end looks like it needs a variable added.

Comment: no, no need book no

Comment: I still do not see the code that checks for a date collision. Would you please paste those lines into a comment for me? I'm not the brightest one in the room but I'd like to try to help you. :)

Comment: When you have previous bookings in a db table, why are you reading from a file or another system (`$url`)? Why not query against the booking table? You could do that with one SQL statement. As @RobMoll asked, where are you comparing against the existing bookings? I only see you checking against the data returned by the target of `$url`.

Comment: One last shot at this: I think I see where you're checking for date clash. I think it's here: `$url2 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/displayBookingData?timeStart=$timeTo&timeEnd=$timeFrom&Room_ID=$Room_ID&Book_No=";` BUT I think it should look like this: `$url2 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/displayBookingData?timeStart=$timeFrom&timeEnd=$timeTo&Room_ID=$Room_ID&Book_No=";` I switched `$timeTo` and `$timeFrom`

Comment: Ah Ha! I think I see where the problem is. You are calling a script that displays bookings between two date-times, right? I nothing is returned, you presume there is no collision. If this function is reading from the same table, then the approach is inefficient and wastes resources. It will also not work for all 4 possible conflicts. If it is the same table, let me know and I'll provide an answer that will properly detect a booking collision.

Comment: This is the original for url2, $url = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE NOT (StartTime > :timeTo OR EndTime < :timeFrom) AND (Book_Status = 'Approve' OR Book_Status = 'Pending') AND Room_ID = :Room_ID";

Comment: @SloanThrasher, Thanks so much dude. Waiting for your answer

Comment: what are the values going through right now? Compare them with the inputs. Are they just times or dates and times? what is the column's type and existing values?

Comment: @SloanThrasher yes, the same table

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Start Time, End Time, and room ID

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I meant. I meant like is it `10:05:45` as hour/min/sec or something else? The column type is DATE or other? What are the POST input values?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner datetime format

Comment: Btw, you need to show us  the actual for this. What you posted isn't using the right function. You're looking for a SELECT and showing us how it's used, it's  values going in, echo out what the query is and compare it with the data in the table. If something doesn't match, you'll need to backtrace and debug. There isn't much else I can say/do.

Answer (score 1):

So, rather than using URLs to check for conflicting bookings and requiring browser refreshes and multiple round trips to the server, this solution tests against the *booking table directly*. The `SQL SELECT` could be easily modified to retrieve a list of conflicting bookings.

This code has **not been tested!** *It may contain typos, errors, etc.*

Check the code comments for info about how it works. If you have questions, ask in the comments.

```
<?php

require_once "../../../config/configPDO.php";
require_once "../../../config/check.php";
$Email = $_SESSION['login_user'];
$UserID = $_SESSION['userid'];

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   

    require '../../../config/PHPMailer/Mailer/Exception.php';
    require '../../../config/PHPMailer/Mailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require '../../../config/PHPMailer/Mailer/SMTP.php';

    $Requested_by = $_POST['Requested_by'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $timeFrom = $_POST['timeFrom'];
    $timeTo = $_POST['timeTo'];

    //to add %20 for space
    $from = rawurlencode($timeFrom);
    $to = rawurlencode($timeTo);

    $Meeting_Description = $_POST['Meeting_Description'];
    $Room_ID = $_POST['Room_ID'];
    $Admin_email = $_POST['Admin_email'];
    $Remark = $_POST['Remark'];
    $Book_Status = $_POST['Book_Status'];
    $StartTime = $date." ".$timeFrom;
    $EndTime = $date." ".$timeTo;


    //  The sql statement could be on one line, but this reads more clearly, and can be echoed easily.
    //  The two expressions  after the room id comparisons test for four conditions.
    //  The first check to see if the new booking is within an existing booking.
    //  The second checks for the other three possibilities:
    //      1.  Starts before booking and ends within booking.
    //      2.  Starts within a booking and ends after the booking.
    //      3.  Starts before a booking and ends after the booking.
    $sql = "";
    $sql .= "SELECT\n";
    $sql .= "   COUNT(*) as `NumConflicts`\n";
    $sql .= "   FROM `booking`\n";
    $sql .= "   WHERE `Book_Date` = :date AND\n";
    $sql .= "       :Room_ID = `Room_ID` AND\n";
    $sql .= "       (\n";
    $sql .= "           (:timeTo_1 BETWEEN `StartTime` AND `EndTime` AND :timeFrom_1 BETWEEN `StartTime` AND `EndTime`) OR\n";
    $sql .= "           (`StartTime` BETWEEN :timeFrom_2 AND :timeTo_2 OR `EndTime` BETWEEN :timeFrom_3 AND :timeTo_3)\n";
    $sql .= "       );";

    $query_1 = $conn->prepare($sql);

    //  For the timeTo and timeFrom values in the SQL statement, they are split into 3 separate 
    //  IDs since an ID can only appear once in a statement to be prepared.
    $query_1->bindparam(':date', $date);
    $query_1->bindparam(':Room_ID', $Room_ID);
    $query_1->bindparam(':timeTo_1', $timeTo);
    $query_1->bindparam(':timeFrom_2', $timeFrom); 
    $query_1->bindparam(':timeTo_2', $timeTo);
    $query_1->bindparam(':timeFrom_3', $timeFrom); 
    $query_1->bindparam(':timeTo_3', $timeTo);
    $query_1->bindparam(':timeFrom_1', $timeFrom); 

    if()$query_1->execute()) {
        if($query_1->rowCount() => 1) {
            $row = $query_1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($row !== false) {
                if($row['NumConflicts'] >= 1) {
                    //  Conflicting Booking(s) Exist.
                    echo "<script>alert('There is at least one other booking that overlaps this booking. Please try again.')</script>
                        <script>window.location = '../../dashboard/admin/dashboard_admin.php'</script>";
                } else {
                    //  No Conflicting Bookings.

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `booking` (`Requested_by`, `Book_Date`, `StartTime`, `EndTime`, `Meeting_Description`, `Room_ID`, `Admin_email`, `Remark`, `Book_Status`) 
                    VALUES(:Requested_by, :Book_Date, :StartTime, :EndTime, :Meeting_Description, :Room_ID, :Admin_email, :Remark, :Book_Status)";
                    $query_2 = $conn->prepare($sql);

                    $query_2->bindparam(':Requested_by', $Requested_by);
                    $query_2->bindparam(':Book_Date', $date);
                    $query_2->bindparam(':StartTime', $StartTime);
                    $query_2->bindparam(':EndTime', $EndTime); 
                    $query_2->bindparam(':Meeting_Description', $Meeting_Description);
                    $query_2->bindparam(':Room_ID', $Room_ID);
                    $query_2->bindparam(':Admin_email', $Admin_email);
                    $query_2->bindparam(':Remark', $Remark);
                    $query_2->bindparam(':Book_Status', $Book_Status);
                    if($query_2->execute()) {
                        echo "<script>alert('Booking successfully saved!')</script>
                            <script>window.location = '../../dashboard/admin/dashboard_admin.php'</script>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<script>alert('Something went wrong saving the booking. Please try again.')</script>
                            <script>window.location = '../../dashboard/admin/dashboard_admin.php'</script>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Definitely useful.

Comment: @RobMoll, Thanks

Comment: Ahmad Albab, did this work for you? Any questions about the code?